# Question regarding evaluating this difference of limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is $\lim_{x \to 1-} ln|x-1| $ - $\lim_{y \to 1+} ln|y-1| $  = 0 since $\lim_{x \to 1-} ln|x-1| $ = -$\infty$ and
$\lim_{y \to 1+} ln|y-1| $ = -$\infty$

hence we can replace $\lim_{y \to 1+} ln|y-1| $ with  $\lim_{x \to 1-} ln|x-1| $

so $\lim_{x \to 1-} ln|x-1| $ - $\lim_{y \to 1+} ln|y-1| $  = $\lim_{x \to 1-} ln|x-1| $ - $\lim_{x \to 1-} ln|x-1| $ = 0 ?

Comment: As in the sense that both result in the indeterminant form inf - inf ?

Comment: Asking for an evaluation of $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\ln\lvert x-1\rvert-\lim_{y\to 1^+}\ln\lvert y-1\rvert$ is just asking for an evaluation of $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$, and the answer is always the same: we define neither $\infty-\infty$ nor $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$.

Comment: Yes but I am curious as what the fallacy is in exchanging the limit of y for x since they both approach the same result?

Comment: Your fallacy is that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\ln \lvert x-1\rvert-\lim_{x\to1^+}\ln\lvert x-1\rvert$ is still $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$.

Comment: Is there a way to conclude this limit does not exist without reaching an indeterminant form?

Comment: Which limit? There are two limits, both of which (don't) exist in the obvious way, and you are trying to compute an operation out of its (reasonably extended) domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129794/discussion-between-user149372-and-saucy-opath).